# Overriding OnDoubleClick() event on a List View

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `MyListView` class that is inheriting from ListView, and is overriding `OnDragDrop()` (and the other necessary events to implement drag and drop). When I place two of these `MyListview`s on a form I am able to drag an item from one of them and drop it to the other one. This part works.

Now I want to override `OnDoubleClick()` to that class such that again if I place two of these `MyListViews` on a form and double clicked on one of them, the item gets removed from that and gets added to the other one. But I can't get my head around how to do this one.
Could you please give me some ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you manage the sleection of the item in a particular way, but you can

- or after handling double-click look for [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) and act on it
- or you can add a code like this using [ListViewHitTestInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listviewhittestinfo.aspx)  class:

  ```
  private override OnDoubleClick(...)    
  {

     ListViewHitTestInfo hit = this.HitTest(e.Location);
     if (hit.Item != null)
     {
        ListViewItem doubleClickedItem = hit.Item; 
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks Sir, but when I want to compile it, it says "There is no suitable method for override" ... also because I am coding in a Class that derives from ListView, I think in your code I should replace "listView1" with "this" .... Right?

Comment: Ok I found what is the problem with that code above. e.Location is not there for DoubleClick event but it IS there for MOUSEDoubleClick event. so I should override MouseDoubleClick event to be able to use you code. Ok so let's say we got the item with the code above. Now the hard part still remains: this is single class and we drop two of its instances on a form, How does it even know about its Source and Target to move the double clicked item between them? Thanks.

Comment: @BDotA: you have [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listview.aspx) property of `ListViewItem`, from which you can access the actual `ListView` whom item was double clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic in your host form by:

- Handle double-click of first ListView
- Remove from first ListView
- Add to second ListView

Unless you are doing this in many different forms - it's not worth complicating it more than that.

EDIT: 
If justified, centralizing can be as easy as adding a method which does the same thing (pseudocode)

```
public void MyForm_OnListViewDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MoveListItem(firstListView, secondListView);
}
// ... 
public static void MoveListItem(ListView source, ListView destination) 
{
   var listItem = source.SelectedItem;
   source.Remove( listItem );
   destination.Add( listItem );
}
```

Comment: yep I was thinking of putting the double click logic in whatever form that will be using this MyListView thing but I guess on code review later my boss will say no! be consistent! move all the logic to one place, etc :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to your title

```
protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDoubleClick(e);
}
```

And here is the answer to your question

[Using DoubleClick event on a inherited class from ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706891/using-doubleclick-event-on-a-inherited-class-from-listview/10707065#10707065)
This just links back to your other, very similar question.