# Using DoubleClick event on a inherited class from ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a single class called MyClass which is inheriting from ListView...so basically it is a list view and I can use it on a form,etc..I have overriden drag and drop events for this class so now if I put two of these controls on a form and drag items from one to the other, it will do it fine.
My problem is with DoubleClick, How can I implement DoubleClick() on this class? so when later I put two of these controls on a form and double click on a item on one of them, it will move it to the other control... Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried the MouseDoubleClick event?  Just asking....  Unless you are asking how you can associate the two to each other?

Comment: @K'Leg : No Sir, I haven't thought about MouseDblCLick and how it can help me, any more clarification on it will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I was only kidding, but now I am wondering.... eitherway, I wrote a complete example for you below, which does both associate two copies of the same control to itself, and implements the doubleclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious how this could be achieved so I tried it.   I created a new windows forms project and created a myClass:ListView(see code below)  Then I added two if the Controls to the Form, and tied them together using the sister property (which I did not really write up as a property)

I added 1 item to myClass1 and 2 Items to myClass2.  When I double click on anyof them, they move to the other listview.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myClass1.sister = myClass2;
        myClass2.sister = myClass1;
    }
}

public class myClass : ListView
{
    //This is where we will store the information about the sister Control
    private myClass _sister;
    //**EDIT**  I changed sister into a property and now it is selectable
    //from the designer.
    public myClass sister { get { return _sister; } set { _sister = value; } }

    public myClass()
    {
    }
    //here is where we override the OnDoubleCLick Event
    protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        //Make sure this control has a sister 
        if (sister != null)
        {
            //add a temporary storage location for the selected Item
            ListViewItem item = this.SelectedItems[0];
            //Remove the Item from the clicked List
            this.Items.Remove(item);
            //Add the Item to the sister List
            ((myClass)sister).Items.Add(item);
        }
        base.OnDoubleClick(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will fire up a new app and wil try your code.

Comment: This is a good solution, although I prefer using HitTest instead of SelectedItems. I have found that in some case (Not on listview, but in datagrid), the mouse event was fired before the selection update which gives the old selected item. And I would also set sister type to ListView instead of control. Or use an interface.

Comment: Yep, cool. we still have do that "wiring" thing tho but I think that's the closest we can get given this problem. Still better than moving the whole DoubleClick logic to the host forms.

Comment: Using "Interface" for the Sister? would you please give me an example on this one. sounds like a professional way of ding this.

Comment: I wouldn't say Professional :) You just need to be certain that sister does have a property Item. If sister is a control, you can't be sure of that and you will have to check every time(reflection?). Using ListView will solve the problem, but you will only be able to transfer items from ListView to another ListView. Using an interface, you will be able to do the transfer to any control which implement this interface. This can be a listview, a treeview of any type of container. Actually instead of items, I would simply make the interface have 1 single function AddItem for more genericity.

Comment: Depending on what is needed, that might be a good solution (In case reciprocity is needed, meaning if a is sister of b then b is also sister of a). But technically speaking, this is not needed. ListView is fine and won't generate any error. Using an interface will simply add the possibility of sistering with other controls than just ListViewes.

Comment: I edited my answer slightly to prevent the designer from sistering it to a different control, now it should only be able to sister to a myClass Object

Comment: Agreed, listview would have been fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?:

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView source = sender as ListView;
        ListViewItem item =  source.HitTest(e.Location).Item;
        if (item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item " + item.Text + " was double clicked on " + source.Name );
        }
    }
```

Sender will tell you which listview was doubleclicked and since you already implemented the drag&drop I guess you should be able to implement the transfer in the same way.

Comment: Ok we get the "item", but how do we know whhat is the source and target to move this item to?

Comment: The sender variable will give you the source. The target can be defined using a simple switch, depending on the logic of you application.

Comment: ah! good call on Sender, Ok that for the first part, How about the harder part? the part that you mention "The target can be defined using a simple switch, depending on the logic of you application."  please explain this a little more. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Well, if you have 2 listviews, let's say lv1, lv2. a simple if(source == lv1) dest = lv2; else dest = lv1; should do. Defining which list view to use given the source depends on your specifications. if you explain your logic, I will give you a better solution.

Comment: We don't know the names of the listviews that developer drops on the form. This code is going to be written inside that class. This is a single glass and has no idea about the target. It is just one list view that we drop two of them on a form and we want it to work with DblClick.

Comment: Then add a field into the custom class in which you tell her which drop target it need to transfer the item to:)

Comment: Hmm..yeah, That's a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by accessing `Parent` on the control, and moving through it's `Controls`:

```
var allMyClasses = this.Parent.Controls.OfType<MyClass>().ToList();

int index = allMyClasses.IndexOf(this);

MyClass target = null;
if (index == allMyClasses.Count - 1)
{
    target = allMyClasses[0];
}
else if (allMyClasses.Count != 0)
{
    target = allMyClasses[index + 1];
}
```

I'm not 100% sure on the exact code (not tested), but the general technique should work well enough.  You, of course, will want null checks on `Parent`, and you'll need to stick these details into MouseDoubleClick, but it should work no problem.

Comment: Hmmm.Yeah. I didn't test it yet but so your idea is to loop through controls on the host form and find the source and target and then the rest of the problem is easy, move an item form this one to that one.

Comment: Yup, that's the summary it has the benefit that you don't have to manually set the 'Sister' Control